# i am getting attribute error while trying to load the dataset form tensorflow_datasets through load

Tags: tensorflow, attributeerror, tensorflow-datasets

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
`Cell In[5], line 4        2 dataset_name = 'imdb_reviews/subwords8k'        3 # Load the IMDb dataset ---->  4 dataset, info = tfds.load(        5     name=dataset_name,        6     split=('train', 'test'),        7     as_supervised=True,        8     with_info=True`
9 )'

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_datasets' has no attribute 'load'

Instead of using load, I used other methods like load_dataset or load_from_tfds.
For example:

`import tensorflow_datasets as tfds              dataset = tfds.load_dataset('dataset_name')`

and tried different version of tensorflow and tensorflow_datasets

Comment: What version of TF and tfds do you use?

Comment: Hi @shatakkshi  you're encountering an AttributeError because the tensorflow_datasets module doesn't have an attribute named load. This could be due to several reasons, including version compatibility issues or incorrect usage of the library and Make sure you're using the correct method for loading datasets from TensorFlow Datasets. The correct method might vary depending on the version you're using.